# Proof of a limit that is very likely closely related to the Wallis product

Tags: limits, infinite-product

How can one prove that

\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{(2 k)^2 \cdot (4k-3)}{(2k-1)^2 \cdot (4k+1)} = \frac{\pi}{4}? \label{eq:limit}
\end{equation}

---

It is very likely that this limit is closely related to the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product). I also validated using Maple that this limit is actually correct:

```
> limit(product((2*k)*(2*k)*(4*k-3)/((2*k-1)*(2*k-1)*(4*k+1)), k = 1 .. n), n = infinity);

Pi/4
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't dividing by the Wallis product give you what you need? IE Show that $\lim \prod  [( 2k+1)(4k-3)] / [ (2k-1)(4k+1) ] = 1/2$, because the product telescopes out to $ (2n+1) / (4n+1) $.

Comment: @CalvinLin Looks like a really good approach: if one expands the product that you mentioned, the factors should "telescope out" and thus the limit becomes very easy to prove.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{aligned}\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2 k)^2 \cdot (4k-3)}{(2k-1)^2 (4k+1)} & =\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2 k)^2  (4k-3)(4k^2-1)}{(2k-1)^2 \cdot (4k+1)(4k^2-1)} \\& =\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2 k)^2  (4k-3)(2k+1)}{(2k-1) (4k+1)(4k^2-1)}  \\& =\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2 k)^2 }{(4k^2-1)} \cdot \prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(4k-3)(2k+1)}{(2k-1)(4k+1)} \\& = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \lim_{ n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(4k-3)}{(2k-1) } \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(2k+1)}{(4k+1) } \\& = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \lim_{ n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(4k-3)}{(2k-1) } \cdot \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(2k-1)}{(4k-3) } \\& = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \lim_{ n \to \infty} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(4k-3)}{(2k-1) } \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(2k-1)}{(4k-3) } \cdot \frac{2n+1}{4n+1} \\& =  \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \lim_{ n \to \infty} \frac{2n+1}{4n+1} = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2+\frac{1}{n}}{4+\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} 
 \\& = \frac{\pi}{4}.  \end{aligned}$

Where the fourth equality is given by the Wallis product.